# How to make Observable from callback

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, ethereum

I need to make observable from

```
window.web3.eth.getCoinbase((error, result) => { ... });
```

Is it a good idea?

```
new Observable<string>(o => {
    this.w.eth.getCoinbase((err, result) => {
        o.next(result);
        o.complete();
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the first half, but you can certainly do what you are doing unless it's triggered by an event? If that is true you can use `fromEvent()`

Comment: You can do this, but I’m not sure if there’s a reason to. You’re not going to get multiple values back from `getCoinbase`. The callback is only fired once (The API switched to Promise in web3 1.0.0).

Comment: It's usually a good idea to use the built-in observable creators wherever possible. Look at [`bindNodeCallback`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindNodeCallback).

Answer (score 8):

RxJS includes a [`bindNodeCallback`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindNodeCallback) observable creator specifically for creating observables from async functions that use Node-style callbacks.

You could use it like this:

```js
const getCoinbaseAsObservable = Observable.bindNodeCallback(
  callback => this.w.eth.getCoinbase(callback)
);

let coinbaseObservable = getCoinbaseAsObservable();
coinbaseObservable.subscribe(
  result => { /* do something with the result */ },
  error => { /* do something with the error */ }
);
```

Note that an arrow function is used to ensure the `getCoinbase` method is called using `this.w.eth` as its context.